# Issues adding value from custom modal in Google Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-slides

I have a function here that is supposed to do the following:

1. Invoke the dropdown html modal and pass what the user selects to a replace function which...
2. finds the instance of "Document Classification: UNDEFINED" in the Google Presentation, and replaces it with "Document Classification: selectValue from the modal".

However when I log the selectValue, all it does is get "Selected value: undefined" and replaces "Document Classification: undefined". What is going on.

- Also I do have a [slide deck](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/18F97xHUOoG9ZQhwIFEBPdLDJmlyhA9dCOX3cZ0U3InM/edit?usp=sharing) and [script](https://script.google.com/d/14crOjlw7HWmJ70Od-oigkkdTt6aV4tkmy5SxDJMcM1A4RX6PM6-LB-Gq/edit?usp=sharing) that I can share externally.

```js
function AddValuesFromModal(selectValue) {
  var documentId = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getId();
    var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("HTML_myHtml")
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(200)
    .setHeight(150);

  var modal = SlidesApp.getUi();
  modal.showModalDialog(htmlDlg, "Document Classification");
  console.log("Getting document log...");
  var body2 = SlidesApp.openById(documentId);
  console.log("Got document!");
  console.log("Selected value: " + selectValue);
  console.log("Start setting value....");
  SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().replaceAllText("Document Classification: UNDEFINED", "Document Classification: " + selectValue, true);
  console.log("Value has been set!");
}
```

```html
<form id="docType">
<select id="selectDocumentType" name="documentClass">
  <option value="PUBLIC">Public</option>
  <option value="INTERNAL">Internal</option>
  <option value="CONFIDENTIAL">Confidential</option>
  <option value="SECRET">Secret</option>
</select>

<hr/>
 <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit();" value="Submit" />
</form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>a
    function formSubmit(){
    Submit();
    closeIt();
    }
   
    
    function Submit() {
    var selectedValue = $('#selectDocumentType').val();
    console.log(selectedValue);
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(closeIt)
        .AddValuesFromModal(selectedValue);
      };
      
    function closeIt(){
      google.script.host.close();
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The 2 steps you've described need to be implemented as separate functions.**

I put together a small example, originally based on your example, but cleaned up a bit.

The desired program flow is:

1. On the server side, call the `showDialog()` function to display the dialog (via a menu or otherwise)
2. On the client side, call the `updateDocumentClassification()` function via `google.script.run` and pass the form element for processing server side (which will be [converted to an object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms))

Here's the example:

#### Code.gs

```
function showDialog() {
  var dialog = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(150);
  SlidesApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(dialog, 'Document Classification');
}

function updateDocumentClassification(formObject) {
  var classification = formObject.documentClass;
  SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().replaceAllText(
      'Document Classification: UNDEFINED', 
      'Document Classification: ' + classification,
      true);
}

function onOpen() {
   SlidesApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('Replace Test')
       .addItem('Replace Text...', 'showModalDialog')
       .addToUi();
}
```

#### dialog.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="docType" onSubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <select id="selectDocumentType" name="documentClass">
        <option value="PUBLIC">Public</option>
        <option value="INTERNAL">Internal</option>
        <option value="CONFIDENTIAL">Confidential</option>
        <option value="SECRET">Secret</option>
      </select>    
      <hr/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(closeDialog)
      .updateDocumentClassification(formObject);
  $('#formDocumentType :submit').attr('disabled', true);
}

function closeDialog(){
  console.log('Closing dialog...');
  google.script.host.close();
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: sweet. Thanks a lot. Seems to work but I think I was experiencing intermittence because of having multiple active google sessions.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. I can run it once after opening the doc but then when I change the state back to origin it doesn't work again until I reload the doc.

Comment: In my example project with the code shown above, I'm able to revert the text back to "UNDEFINED" and successfully replace it again without reloading. Is there any more context you can provide? Error messages? Logs?

Comment: [20-01-15 21:16:21:418 EST] HtmlService.HtmlOutput.setWidth([200]) [0 seconds]

[20-01-15 21:16:21:419 EST] HtmlService.HtmlOutput.setHeight([150]) [0 seconds]

[20-01-15 21:16:21:419 EST] SlidesApp.getUi() [0 seconds]

[20-01-15 21:16:21:497 EST] Ui.showModalDialog([HtmlOutput, Document Classification]) [0.077 seconds]

[20-01-15 21:16:21:499 EST] Execution succeeded [0.083 seconds total runtime]

Comment: Here's an example of the last 5 executions in showDialog() when it fails after reverted back to UNDEFINED

Comment: I figured it out! There was an issue with the closeit function. Removed closeIt() from form submit and it worked. Must have been a latency issue with my browser. I have submitted an edit for review.

Comment: Gotcha. I used your example as a starting point, but went ahead and cleaned it up a bit further. Take another look if you get a chance to see some further simplifications I put into place.